# Spin Verification, verifying a variable reaches a certain value

Tags: concurrency, verification, model-checking, spin, promela

this is my first Q on Stack Exchange so if there's anything that's breaking guidelines please let me know.

I have a program written in Promela for a college OS and concurrent systems class. There are two processes running that increment a variable n. Our task is to write the processes and then use the verification tool in Spin to prove that it is possible for n to take on the value 4. I've had a read through all of the command line arguments and messed around but nothing strikes out to me as the "insert this modifier followed by a variable name to check all it's possible values."

```
byte n;

proctype p()
{
    byte countp = 0;
    byte temp;
    do
    :: countp != 2 -> temp = n; temp = temp + 1; n = temp; countp = countp + 1;
    :: countp >= 2 -> break;
    od
}

proctype q()
{

    byte countq = 0;

    do
    :: countq != 2 -> n = n + 1; countq = countq + 1;
    :: countq >= 2 -> break;
    od
}

init
{
    run p();
    run q();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, though as a teacher I would prefer the *ltl* based one, since at least it shows you understand how to use it.

---

**Monitor Process.**

This is by far the simplest, conceptually: you simply add a process that asserts that `n != 4` at any time, and then check whether this assertion eventually fails or not.

```cpp
byte n;

active proctype p()
{
    byte countp = 0;
    byte temp;
    do
    :: countp != 2 -> temp = n; temp = temp + 1; n = temp; countp = countp + 1;
    :: countp >= 2 -> break;
    od
}

active proctype q()
{

    byte countq = 0;

    do
    :: countq != 2 -> n = n + 1; countq = countq + 1;
    :: countq >= 2 -> break;
    od
}

active proctype monitor()
{
    do
        :: true -> assert(n != 4);
    od;
}
```

*Note: the loop in the monitor process is totally unnecessary, but it makes its purpose more clear to beginners.*

You can verify this program with the following one liner:

```sh
~$ spin -search -bfs buggy_01.pml
```

**Spin** finds a counter-example in zero-time:

```sh
Depth=10 States=56 Transitions=84 Memory=128.195    
pan:1: assertion violated (n!=4) (at depth 19)
pan: wrote buggy_01.pml.trail

(Spin Version 6.4.3 -- 16 December 2014)
Warning: Search not completed
    + Breadth-First Search
    + Partial Order Reduction

Full statespace search for:
    never claim             - (none specified)
    assertion violations    +
    cycle checks            - (disabled by -DSAFETY)
    invalid end states      +

State-vector 28 byte, depth reached 19, errors: 1
      215 states, stored
             215 nominal states (stored-atomic)
      181 states, matched
      396 transitions (= stored+matched)
        0 atomic steps
hash conflicts:         0 (resolved)

Stats on memory usage (in Megabytes):
    0.011       equivalent memory usage for states (stored*(State-vector + overhead))
    0.290       actual memory usage for states
  128.000       memory used for hash table (-w24)
  128.195       total actual memory usage

pan: elapsed time 0 seconds
```

You can actually check the execution trace that violates the assertion with:

```sh
~$ spin -t -p -g -l buggy_01.pml
```

The options have the following meaning:

- `-t`: replay the `.trail` counter-example generated by spin
- `-p`: print all statements
- `-g`: print all global variables
- `-l`: print all local variables

This is the output:

```sh
using statement merging
  1:    proc  2 (monitor:1) buggy_01.pml:27 (state 1)   [(1)]
  2:    proc  1 (q:1) buggy_01.pml:19 (state 1) [((countq!=2))]
  3:    proc  0 (p:1) buggy_01.pml:8 (state 1)  [((countp!=2))]
  4:    proc  1 (q:1) buggy_01.pml:19 (state 2) [n = (n+1)]
        n = 1
  5:    proc  1 (q:1) buggy_01.pml:19 (state 3) [countq = (countq+1)]
        q(1):countq = 1
  6:    proc  1 (q:1) buggy_01.pml:19 (state 1) [((countq!=2))]
  7:    proc  1 (q:1) buggy_01.pml:19 (state 2) [n = (n+1)]
        n = 2
  8:    proc  1 (q:1) buggy_01.pml:19 (state 3) [countq = (countq+1)]
        q(1):countq = 2
  9:    proc  1 (q:1) buggy_01.pml:20 (state 4) [((countq>=2))]
 10:    proc  0 (p:1) buggy_01.pml:8 (state 2)  [temp = n]
        p(0):temp = 2
 11:    proc  0 (p:1) buggy_01.pml:8 (state 3)  [temp = (temp+1)]
        p(0):temp = 3
 12:    proc  0 (p:1) buggy_01.pml:8 (state 4)  [n = temp]
        n = 3
 13:    proc  0 (p:1) buggy_01.pml:8 (state 5)  [countp = (countp+1)]
        p(0):countp = 1
 14:    proc  0 (p:1) buggy_01.pml:8 (state 1)  [((countp!=2))]
 15:    proc  0 (p:1) buggy_01.pml:8 (state 2)  [temp = n]
        p(0):temp = 3
 16:    proc  0 (p:1) buggy_01.pml:8 (state 3)  [temp = (temp+1)]
        p(0):temp = 4
 17:    proc  0 (p:1) buggy_01.pml:8 (state 4)  [n = temp]
        n = 4
 18:    proc  0 (p:1) buggy_01.pml:8 (state 5)  [countp = (countp+1)]
        p(0):countp = 2
 19:    proc  0 (p:1) buggy_01.pml:9 (state 6)  [((countp>=2))]
spin: buggy_01.pml:27, Error: assertion violated
spin: text of failed assertion: assert((n!=4))
 20:    proc  2 (monitor:1) buggy_01.pml:27 (state 2)   [assert((n!=4))]
spin: trail ends after 20 steps
#processes: 3
        n = 4
 20:    proc  2 (monitor:1) buggy_01.pml:26 (state 3)
 20:    proc  1 (q:1) buggy_01.pml:22 (state 9) <valid end state>
 20:    proc  0 (p:1) buggy_01.pml:11 (state 11) <valid end state>
3 processes created
```

as you can see, it reports (one) of the possible execution traces that leads to the assertion violation.

---

**LTL.**

One can think of several *ltl properties* that can help to verify whether `n` will eventually be equal to `4`. One of such properties, is `[] (n != 4)`, which reads:

> starting from the initial state, in every reachable state along all outgoing paths it is always `true` that `n` is different from `4`.

The new model looks like this:

```cpp
byte n;

active proctype p()
{
    byte countp = 0;
    byte temp;
    do
    :: countp != 2 -> temp = n; temp = temp + 1; n = temp; countp = countp + 1;
    :: countp >= 2 -> break;
    od
}

active proctype q()
{

    byte countq = 0;

    do
    :: countq != 2 -> n = n + 1; countq = countq + 1;
    :: countq >= 2 -> break;
    od
}

ltl p0 { [] (n != 4) }
```

You verify this property pretty much in the same way as you would with the assertion. To keep this answer short, I won't copy-and-paste the whole output here, and just list the commands used:

```sh
~$ spin -search -bfs buggy_02.pml
ltl p0: [] ((n!=4))
Depth=10 States=40 Transitions=40 Memory=128.195    
pan:1: assertion violated  !( !((n!=4))) (at depth 15)
pan: wrote buggy_02.pml.trail

...

Full statespace search for:
    never claim             + (p0)
    ...
State-vector 28 byte, depth reached 15, errors: 1
...

~$ spin -t -p -g -l buggy_02.pml
...
```

---

If you want to guarantee that `n` is always eventually equal to `4`, then you should look into some *mutual exclusion* approach to protect your *critical section* or, alternatively, check the [documentation](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/d_step.html) of `d_step {}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a great answer. Exactly what I was looking for. So are LTL's used to prove or disprove certain things in a process? Was there a specific reason for calling the ltl p0?

Comment: @JackCassidy You can use any name, `p0` stands for `property 0`, and it's just my personal naming convention for *'silly'* properties. Names are used in the case in which you have multiple properties, because with *spin* you check 1 property at a time. *LTL* is used to state properties that you want to verify for being *true* or *false* on your program. Which way you encode a property depends on whether you want a *counter-example* or not: if the property is true, you are not given one.